# Which creatures are damaged by Cure spells?

Tags: ps4, final-fantasy-12

If I am recalling correctly, there were some creatures in the original Final Fantasy 12 that could be damaged by Cure spells. If they were weak to Holy magicks, then they would take damage from spells like Cure, Cura, Curaga, and Curaja.

I've been testing this on a few creatures (Skeletons, Zombies, etc) but it still seems to give them health instead of damaging them. Is this mechanic still possible in The Zodiac Age, and if so, what creatures are damaged by Cure spells?

Comment: The [White Mage](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/White_Mage_(Final_Fantasy_XII)) says *using white magicks to heal and buff the party and damage undead enemies*, so it does appear to be possible in the Zodiac Age version. I wonder why it would heal them

Comment: @Wondercricket My thoughts exactly! And considering the Holy spell is an end-game magick, and considering how slow it is to cast and do damage, using Cura spells on a group of undead seems like the more tactical choice!

Comment: Probably a long shot, but were you casting the Cure spells as a White Mage or another class that could cast White Magicks spells?

Comment: @Wondercricket Yep, Penelo is my White Made, and I had her try to Cure a Skull Defender in the Barheim Passage, but it just healed him instead.

Comment: I've got a free-ish weekend and my old copy of FF12 for PS2. I'll go find some Ghosts in the Necrohol of Nabudis and see whether I can damage them with Cure spells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further testing on my own, I have discovered the following;

Due to the class system, White Magic healing spells will only do damage to Holy-weak enemies if it comes from a White Mage. Cure spells that come from other classes will instead heal Holy-weak enemies.

This was not the case in the original PS2 Final Fantasy 12, as every character could offensively damage Holy-weak enemies with Cure spells.

Comment: This is good info to know!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in FF12 for PS2, Holy-weak enemies are damaged by Cure spells.

I went back to my most recent save (level 64-65 at the Teleport Stone in the Nabreus Deadlands). While working my way into the Necrohol of Nabudis, I came across a [Leynir](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Leynir), and then inside the Necrohol, I found an [Oversoul](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Oversoul_(Final_Fantasy_XII)); both were killed by my "Foe: holy-weak/Curaga" gambit. At first I couldn't tell if it was working; I ended up turning Libra on to watch their health meter dropping.

As for which enemies should be damaged by these spells, take a look at the [Undead](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Undead) page on the FF wiki, which lists a total of 66 enemies that are undead (many of which are either marks, rare game, or bosses).

Comment: We know this works on PS2, but the OP is asking about the recently released PS4 version - which didn't appear to damage undead

Comment: Well, I did try it out last night, and Penelo (my white mage) was able to damage some Zombie Knights in the Sochen Cave Palace with Cura. I forgot to test it with non-White Mage characters (Vaan knows Curaga).

Comment: Further testing reveals that Vaan's Curaga spell (Knight/Foebreaker) does indeed HEAL enemies. So only the White Mage can use healing spells offensively.